# Unknown Meta tag in all responses in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, seo, meta-tags

I am getting an unknown response in all requests to a laravel 5.3 app.
eg if i make an ajax call that expects json response. i get that json response but with an unwanted meta tag. due to which i am not able to decode json response.
this is what i get when i make an ajax call to get json response.

`<meta name="verify-admitad" content="8e6063a16f" />`
{'some valid json'}

also status code is 200

i get this meta tag not only in ajax but also with normal request.

Comment: How do you add meta tag automatically for all responses in your code?

Comment: i am new to laravel and i don't know how to do so.

Comment: It's getting added somewhere, find out where: `grep -R "verify-admitad" /path/to/laravel`

Comment: Change your server credentials to prevent this to happen in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out what was going on that meta tag was added at the top of the index.php file, and hence i was getting it in all requests. But now the question is where did it came from, did i was hacked. i am using hostgator for webhosting.
can anyone suggests me how to avoid this in future.